# How do I render a JTable inside of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, nested

I am trying to nest a JTable inside of another JTable's column (using a CellRenderer).

Example (erroneous) output:

[image]

Why does the following example not output a table within a table?

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable table = new JTable(new CustomTableModel());
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Person.class, new CustomRenderer());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return new Person("Bob");
        } else {
            return "is awesome!";
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CustomRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        JTable t = new JTable(new CustomTableModel());
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
        return this;
    }
}

class Person {

    public String name = "";

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the sub table to a scroll pane. Instead, try adding the table to the center position of a JPanel with a BorderLayout, then add the tables header to the NORTH position

The main reason for this is the scroll pane will not be interactive and may hide data

**Updated**

I'm on phone, so it's hard to read the code :P

In your main table model, you need to override the getColumnClass method and make sure you are retuning Person.class for the required column (and the correct class types for the other columns to)

Comment: I will try the scroll pane, but w.r.t. not returning this - I was under the assumption that it is best practice to instantiate the main component of a renderer only once. EDIT: I still receive a String value without the scroll pane - I will upload a screenshot.

Comment: It is better if you can reduce the number if short lived objects, but, your creating the JTable on each interaction anyway

Comment: That's true, but those are secondary points since the scroll pane wasn't preventing the JTable from displaying.